# How/Where to store 'pepper' value in app? (Hash password with salt & Pepper)

Tags: asp.net, cryptography, sha512

I create a page with webforms autehnticate. I store logins and passwords in a database. Passwords are hashed (SHA512) with random salt value (RNGCryptoServiceProvider). Additionaly before hashing I mix original user password with salt value. I would like to add some pepper value, but I'm not sure where it is best to put the value of the pepper [I guess that directly in the code is a poor idea ;)] If in web.config then how to do this?

Or maybe I do not need pepper at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)